# Add class to all child div's except when it matches $current_person

Tags: javascript, jquery

The user lists a bunch of available times for riding lessons. Each lesson has a trainer associated with it.

```
$item_html_start = '<div class="item ' .$current_trainer_slug. ' ' .$current_ridetype. ' ' .$current_day. '">';
$item_html_end = '</div>';

$output[$current_ridetype][$current_day] .= $item_html_start . get_the_title() . $item_html_end;
```

and generated this:

```
<div class="item mirja ponnylektioner mandag">16:00 P2</div>
<div class="item lizzie ponnylektioner mandag">16:00 P3</div>
<div class="item sven ponnylektioner mandag">16:00 P4</div>
<div class="item johan ponnylektioner mandag">16:00 P5</div>
```

etc...
It's simple enough.

What I want, is to have buttons that on click, will add a class to each `.item` div that does not match its class. So if I click on `<button class="lizzie" name="lizzie">Lizzie</button>` for instance, it will add the class `inactive` to all `.item` div's that does NOT match `lizzie`. When pressing it again, all classes are removed. If I press another button, like `sven` for example, same thing happens but for the buttons with class `sven`, naturally.

I have very little (ok, barely any) experience with javascript, so the only thing I could think of was `.addClass`, but I'm not sure how I'd go about using that without violating [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) all over the place.

The site has jQuery included, so might as well use that if it makes life easier?

Thanks.

Comment: Use .toggleClass() to add/remove the class for all elements

Comment: you can use `toggleClass()` for the hide/show any element. The element that is clicked will be displayed and make hide all the `siblings` of that class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use .toggleClass to add/remove class to the element that match the selection. For example:

```
$('.item').not('.lizzie').toggleClass('inactive');
```

Comment: Even though I liked @David Thomas' answer, this is the one that nudged me in the right direction this time, so I'll leave the Checkmark here.

Answer (score 2):

With CSS alone, though bear in mind we don't add any class here instead we simply style the elements directly:

```
/* here we select all <div> elements
   with a class of 'item'
   which do not match the '.lizzie' selector: */
div.item:not(.lizzie) {
  color: red;
  opacity: 0.5;
```

```css
div.item:not(.lizzie) {
  color: red;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="item mirja ponnylektioner mandag">16:00 P2</div>
<div class="item lizzie ponnylektioner mandag">16:00 P3</div>
<div class="item sven ponnylektioner mandag">16:00 P4</div>
<div class="item johan ponnylektioner mandag">16:00 P5</div>
```

With JavaScript:

```
// here we use Array.from():
Array.from(
  // to turn the NodeList returned by
  // document.querySelectorAll()
  // (using the same selector as explained above)
  // into an Array:
  document.querySelectorAll('div.item:not(.lizzie)')

// we then use Array.prototype.forEach() to iterate
// over the Array of elements:
).forEach(

  // using an Array Function syntax:
  // to use Element.classList.add() to add the
  // 'inactive' class-name to each of the elements:
  notLizzieElement => notLizzieElement.classList.add('inactive')
);
```

```js
Array.from(
  document.querySelectorAll('div.item:not(.lizzie)')
).forEach(
  notLizzieElement => notLizzieElement.classList.add('inactive')
);
```

```css
.inactive {
  opacity: 0.5;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="item mirja ponnylektioner mandag">16:00 P2</div>
<div class="item lizzie ponnylektioner mandag">16:00 P3</div>
<div class="item sven ponnylektioner mandag">16:00 P4</div>
<div class="item johan ponnylektioner mandag">16:00 P5</div>
```

This is exactly the same as the following approach, but without using Arrow syntax:

```
// here we use Array.from():
Array.from(
  // to turn the NodeList returned by
  // document.querySelectorAll()
  // (using the same selector as explained above)
  // into an Array:
  document.querySelectorAll('div.item:not(.lizzie)')

// we then use Array.prototype.forEach() to iterate
// over the Array of elements:
).forEach(function(notLizzieElement)}
  notLizzieElement.classList.add('inactive')
});
```

```js
Array.from(
  document.querySelectorAll('div.item:not(.lizzie)')
).forEach(function(notLizzieElement){
  notLizzieElement.classList.add('inactive')
});
```

```css
.inactive {
  opacity: 0.5;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="item mirja ponnylektioner mandag">16:00 P2</div>
<div class="item lizzie ponnylektioner mandag">16:00 P3</div>
<div class="item sven ponnylektioner mandag">16:00 P4</div>
<div class="item johan ponnylektioner mandag">16:00 P5</div>
```

References:

- CSS:

  - [CSS Negation pseudo-class `:not()`](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/:not).
- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).
  - [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
  - [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Comment: Nice answer, though `NodeList.prototype.forEach()` is available in all browsers since at least 2013 now (especially in browsers that do support arrow-functions); see also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach

Comment: How would "CSS alone" work upon clicking a button? There are many trainers, so merely copy/pasting that code and changing it's class-name would simply make all look the same, so I'm confused that two people have suggested a pure CSS solution. Perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: @Patrick: in all honesty I somehow managed to forget, or overlook, the 'on click...' requirement. Though I think it's probably possible, albeit in an overly complicated CSS-hack type way; which if I can figure it out I'll post, but would certainly recommend that you take the JavaScript approach in this instance.

Comment: @feeela Not once did I say I wanted a copy/paste solution, but I wanna understand what I'm doing. "With CSS alone" suggests that no other language would be necessary. THAT is what I wondered about.

Comment: @DavidThomas Ah ok that makes more sense :)

Comment: @Patrik: incidentally, the hideous - *absolutely not recommended* - CSS hack: https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/fw8vc7ey/ (please: **do not use this**).

Comment: @DavidThomas Haha that's awesome. Don't worry though, I won't go that route :)

Answer (score 0):

you could use jQuery selector `.not()`

```
 $(selector).not($current_person).addClass('yourClass')
```

or `:not()`

```
$(selector:not(Selector)).addClass('yourClass')
```

or you could use pure css `:not()`

```
:not(selector) {
    color: #e2e2e2;
}
```

where selector can be a valid css selecor

Comment: So essentially, I have to loop through all trainers in PHP and add a piece of javascript to each and every one? That's the "against DRY" part I mentioned... I don't understand the pure CSS way either. There are more than one trainer, so how does the CSS dynamically apply its style when the user clicks something?..